# jQuery wrap label around plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wrap a label around plain text that doesn't have something to easily target it.

For example, this:

```
<div class="checbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
     some text
</div>
```

Should become:

```
<div class="checbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
     <label>some text</label>
</div>
```

If I could modify the HTML this would be trivial, but I cannot.

With jQuery how could I wrap this "some text" with a label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the html structure is constant then, you want to wrap the last child of the div with class `checkbox`

```js
$($('.checbox')[0].lastChild).wrap('<label />')
```

```css
label {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
     some text
</div>
```

---

If you have multiple elements like this then

```js
$('.checbox').each(function(){
  $(this.lastChild).wrap('<label />')
})
```

```css
label {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
     some text
</div>
<div class="checbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
     some text 2
</div>
```

Comment: @Martin see also [text nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195868/what-is-a-text-node-its-uses-document-createtextnode)

Comment: That works well, but it only targets the first. I actually have 5 or so that I need to target.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/zxhcb6sw/

It'll wrap all text nodes inside the div:

```
$( ".checbox" )
.contents()
.filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
})
.wrap( "<label></label>" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciate it