# $(this).html() is not working when jquery version is v1.10.2

Tags: jquery

the below code is a sample code where `$(this).html()` is not working when using `jquery` version v1.10.2 but the same code is working when `jquery` version is v1.6.4. see my code and give me suggestion how to get rid of this because our product is using `jquery` version v1.10.2.

```
$elements.each(function () {
    //alert($(this).text());
    if ($(this).html() === null) {

        $item = $('<li class="current" />').append($(this));
    }
    else {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).text()))) {
            $item = $('<li />').append($(this));

        }
        else {
            $item = $('<li class="navpage"/>').append($(this));
            //alert($(this).text());
        }
    }
    $list.append($item);
});
```

full code found in this js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/41s1pq3a/38/

just see & run the `jsfiddle` code with 2 different version called v1.6.4 and v1.10.2 then understand `$(this).html()` is not working.

looking for suggestion what i need to change in code as a result `$(this).html()` will start working in v1.10.2. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comparison

```
if ($(this).html() === null) {
    $item = $('<li class="current" />').append($(this));
}
```

is too risky. And apparently it breaks in more recent version of jQuery. Just use

```
if (!$(this).html()) {
    $item = $('<li class="current" />').append($(this));
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/41s1pq3a/40/

Comment: The original comparison was `if ($(this).html() === null) {...` . Sorry for being a weisenheimer. ;-)

Comment: @DavidDomain Thank you, this is important!

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the [html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) directly on [TextNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195868/what-is-a-text-node-its-uses-document-createtextnode), a `console.log` from a `$(this)` inside the `$elements.each` returns:

```
<TextNode textContent="\n           1 \n            ">
```

[This answer explains TextNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17196184/1326147) well, and the reasons to operate on them. to Thus you should use the [text function](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead to get the string you want.