# Security concern over method of removing tags from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, code-injection

I am using [findAndReplaceDOMText](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText), a library that lets you wrap text that spans multiple tags.

Consider wrapping `o b` in `<em>` tags in the following html:

```
<p>foo <span>bar</span></p>
```

It generates the following:

```
<p>fo<em>o </em><span><em>b</em>ar</span></p>
```

This works great. My concern is that my strategy for *removing* these tags may open up the potential for code injection. The below code *does* work, I am just worried of potential code injection opportunities, particularly because I'm working on a chrome extension, so the target page's HTML may be malformed.

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export default function clearMarks() {
  $(".deepSearch-highlight").parent().each(function() {
    const contents = []
    const $parent = $(this)
    $parent.contents().each(function() {
      const $node = $(this)
      let html

      if ($node.hasClass("deepSearch-highlight")) {
        html = $node.html()
      }
      else if (this.nodeName === "#text") {
        html = this.data
      }
      else {
        html = this.outerHTML
      }
      contents.push(html)
    })
    $parent.html(contents.join(""))
  })
}
```

My goal is to restore the html to *exactly* what it was before it was transformed with findAndReplaceDOMText. In the "additional information" section you can see how a simpler `clearMarks` function will result in a change to the number of text nodes.

Does my strategy have any security vulnerabilities I'm missing? Is there a more secure/more elegant/generally better way of achieving my goal?

---

### Additional Information:

- I am using the [findAndReplaceDOMText](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText#presetprose) option `preset: "prose"` which:

  > Ignore non-textual elements (E.g. `<script>`, `<svg>`, `<optgroup>,``, etc.)
- As an aside, the much simpler `$(this).replaceWith($(this).html())` results in an explosion in the number of text nodes. With the above example we would result in: `<p>"fo""o "<span>"b""ar"</span></p>` (where text nodes are denoted with `"`). That's causes problems if you try reapplying `findAndReplaceDOMText` in addition to being generally smelly.
- The inserted `span` elements have a class of `.deepSearch-highlight` (in contrast to the above example which wraps text in `em`'s. See the full code below.

.

```
import $ from "jquery"
import findAndReplaceDomText from "findandreplacedomtext"

import buildRegex from "../../shared/buildRegex"
import scrollToElement from "./scrollToElement"


export default function search(queryParams) {
  const regex = buildRegex(queryParams)
  findAndReplaceDomText($('body')[0], {
    find: regex,
    replace: createHighlight,
    preset: "prose",
    filterElements,
  })
  scrollToElement($(".deepSearch-current-highlight"))
}

function createHighlight(portion, match) {
  var wrapped = document.createElement("span")
  var wrappedClasses = "deepSearch-highlight"
  if (match.index === 0) {
    wrappedClasses += " deepSearch-current-highlight"
  }
  wrapped.setAttribute("class", wrappedClasses)
  wrapped.setAttribute("data-highlight-index", match.index)
  wrapped.appendChild(document.createTextNode(portion.text))
  return wrapped
}

function filterElements(elem) {
  const $elem = $(elem)
  return $elem.is(":visible") && !$elem.attr("aria-hidden")
}
```

Comment: For removal you shouldn't use inner/outerhtml. Simply operating on text nodes and replacing the to-be-removed node with its child list should do the job.

Comment: `html = $node.html()` -> vulnerability. That's what I can say from just looking at your code - you get raw input. Same as getting `this.outerHTML`. that content, which could be a malicious `<script>` is then put unfiltered using a `.html(contents.join(""))` which would enact whatever HTML is there. However, to be honest, I'm still unclear on what's the actual goal here. Why do you need to take content from somewhere to elsewhere? And what exact attack vector are you trying to mitigate? Is the date you're extracting come from the _same_ user or _elsewhere_?

Comment: @vlaz I'm building a chrome extension which lets the user search for their own regex on the current page (among other things). I use `findAndReplaceDOMText` to wrap text in a highlighted `span` to indicate matches. The `clearMarks` function is intended to restore the DOM to the state *before* I ran `findAndReplaceDOMText`. In the case of the example that is to say: `<p>foo <span>bar</span></p>`.

Comment: @HenryBaughman so at which point would a code injection be a problem? Where would the malicious code come from? I'm trying to understand the functionality. Right now, it sounds like even _if_ there is a code injection it'd be caused by the user. However, I'm still not clear on the full picture, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @vlaz Because I have the [`preset: "prose"`](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText#presetprose) and filterElements option set for `findAndReplaceDOMText`, I shouldn't ever be in replacing a genuine `script` tag. I'm more concerned about the possibility of turning an unescaped text node (e.g., with `<` instead of `&lt;`) into a piece of functioning JS. I'm not exactly sure how or even if this could happen -- hence the question.

Comment: @the8472 That was close to my original solution, but that results in the proliferation of [text nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195868/what-is-a-text-node-its-uses-document-createtextnode). With the example from my question, we would get: `<p>"fo""o "<span>"b""ar"</span></p>` (where text nodes are surrounded with `"`). That causes problems if you try reapplying findAndReplaceDOMText in addition to being generally smelly. I need to restore the html to *exactly* the way it was before I first applied `findAndReplaceDOMText`

Comment: If you need to restore the DOM, how about simply cloning it, manipulating the clone and hiding the original? That way you are safe. You will likely need a way to find the original node, so you could add your own attribute, like `<span data-myID="73" />` your cloned object can then look like `<span data-myLinkID="73 />` - when you need to "restore", you find all the cloned objects remove them and use the custom ID to lookup the originals and simply show them again. It should be quite fast and quite safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not process HTML if you only want to remove elements and retain their text children. You should use plain DOM APIs that move text and element nodes. Using the HTML parser gives suboptimal performance at best and creates security holes at worst.

> As an aside, the much simpler $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()) results in an explosion in the number of text nodes.

This can be solved by applying [Node.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) to an ancestor.