# Why html permits bulk text (text without being between tags) in the main body, isn't it 'wrong'?

Tags: html, text, bulk

```
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
bulk text
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand why it would be "wrong"?

Comment: Perhaps this can shed more light on text nodes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195868/what-is-a-text-node-its-uses-document-createtextnode

Comment: Tags add formatting. Plain text is just interpreted by the browser as text that goes "roughly" where you typed it on the page. However, doing so is terrible practice and shouldnt be done

Comment: Thank you Takarii this is exactly the answer i was looking for.