# Identify NextSibling in XMLHTTP response

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am still trying to learn about NextSibling and I am using XMLHTTP in excel VBA.
Here's the HTML for the element

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled list-specification">
                                            <li><span>ID</span> <span class="text-info">22928</span></li>
                                            
                                            <li><span>Category</span> <span class="text-info">Mechanical</span></li>
                                                <li><span>Discipline</span> <span class="text-info">Mechanical  </span></li>
                                                                                            <li><span>Commodity</span> <span class="text-info">Pipe</span></li>
                                                 <li><span>Sub commodity</span> <span class="text-info">12 In Pipe </span></li>
                                                                                            <li><span>UOM</span> <span class="text-info">EA</span></li>
                                                                                              <li><span>Available quantity</span> <span class="text-info">30</span></li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <li><span>Age</span> <span class="text-info">8</span></li>
                                                                                        
                                        </ul>
```

I have used this line to spot on the first span in the li (lists) so as to identify the headers for each part

```
Set post = html.querySelectorAll(".list-specification li span")
```

Then I used loops like that

```
    For j = 0 To post.Length - 1
        If post.Item(j).innerText = "ID" Then
            Debug.Print post.Item(j).NextSibling.innerText
        End If
    Next j
```

I got an error when trying to use `NextSibling`. I feel stuck as for that `NextSibling` .. Can you guide me?
for example ID is the first in the list and I would like to get that ID based on my approach

I got an error when trying `nextElementSibling`

```
Sub Test()
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object, i As Long
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "Get", "C:\Sample.html", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set post = html.querySelectorAll(".list-specification li span")
    For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
        If post.Item(i).innerText = "ID" Then
            MsgBox post.Item(i).nextElementSibling.innerText: Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing another `NextSibling` and then you should find it working:

```
Set post = Html.querySelectorAll(".list-specification li span")
For j = 0 To post.Length - 1
    If post.Item(j).innerText = "ID" Then
        MsgBox post.Item(j).NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next j
```

Comment: Amazing. That worked well. But I couldn't get it. Can you give a simple explanation why two NextSiblings?

Comment: There was likely an invisible space in between.

Answer (score 1):

The correct property to access I was expecting to be [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling), but it seems VBA does not implement this.

> The ***NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling*** read-only property
>   returns the element immediately following the specified one in its
>   parent's children list, or null if the specified element is the last
>   one in the list.

You can however, more correctly, simply take the next index in `post` i.e. `post.item(1)`. You are collecting both headers and values in the same nodeList so you can use odd/even distinction to separate headers from values.

You can see this if you run the following in console:

```
post = document.querySelectorAll(".list-specification li span");
var res = ''; for (let [i] of Object.entries(post)) {res += post.item(`${i}`).innerText + ' '};console.log(res);
```

Spans are [inline containers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) and you can see from html that you have a space between spans which is part of the parent `li` and [this becomes a child text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195868/what-is-a-text-node-its-uses-document-createtextnode). This is why your `nextSibling` hits a [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) and errors with the attempt at `.innerText` accessor. You would want a text node property such as `.nodeValue` (if you were at the right node).

[image]

You can step through, in the console, and see the different properties in action:

[image]

As `nextElementSibling` is not implemented in VBA you would need to chain `nextSibling`, as per @Sim's answer, if you want to explore `nextSibling` to solve this particular navigation.  However, note that a test of `nodeType` would avoid throwing an error as you could then apply the appropriate accessor.

Comment: Thanks a lot my tutor. I will try it.

Comment: I recommend the mozilla pages. That is where I go. And use the Console to test things out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried what you have written in the console and it works well and as illustrated but this doesn't work in the code. I have added the code so as to test on your side.

Comment: I have edited the answer. That is a good spot. I hadn't realised this wasn't implemented in VBA. That makes @Sim's answer likely a better one for solving your query if you want to use nextSibling rather than index into the collection you have retrieved in post.