# Parsing a specific text value with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

[image]

[image]

Hey does anyone know how to parse the "Light rain", " 7°C", and "Limited"? These are stored as #text so that's kind of throwing me off. For reference, to parse "Temperature:", it would be Element element5 = doc.select("strong").get(3);
Thanks!

Comment: In order to parse them, you need a grammar of some kind.  What is the grammar?

Comment: JSoup parses HTML text. You don't have to parse anything.

Comment: Perhaps "parse" is the incorrect word? I'm trying to access "Light Rain" as doc.select("text).get(number) but that seems to produce a null pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodes from your example are called [text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195868/what-is-a-text-node-its-uses-document-createtextnode). In Jsoup, you can read the text nodes of a node by using the [`text()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text()) method. So given your example using Jsoup we'd select the `td` element and then use `text()` to get it's text value.

However, this would also output the text value from any child nodes, so in your case this would produce `Weather: Light rain` as a single string. Fortunately, Jsoup also has a [`ownText()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText()) method that only extracts the value from the text nodes that are a direct descendant of the element (and not all children). So given your example code, you could write it like this:

```java
Element element5 = doc.select("td").get(3);
String value = element5.ownText()
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the response! The code above seems to give "Temperature:" and not "7°C". Is there a way to access the "7°C"?

Comment: You're right and I've edited my answer with new code and a better explanation of what's going on. First of all, you need to select the `td` element instead of the `strong` element since you're interested in the value and the value is a child of the `td` element and not the `strong` element. After that, use the `ownText` method to extract the value from the text node (while ignoring the `strong` child)

Comment: Oh I didn't even know about the ownText thing, you're a lifesaver. Thank you so much Martin!

Comment: No problem. You may also be interested in `getElementsContainingOwnText`or `getElementsMatchingOwnText`. This will allow you to search for nodes using a key like `Temperature:` or `Temperature` (regex) instead of the row number. Parsing tables using row numbers may break if a row is ever added or swapped in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variuos ways to extract required text and one of them is `td.childNode(1).toString()` and complete solution is mentioned below:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Parse HTML String using JSoup library

    String HTMLSTring = "<html>\n" +
            " <head></head>\n" +
            " <body>\n" +
            "  <table class=\"table\"> \n" +
            "   <tbody>\n" +
            "    <tr> \n" +
            "     <td><strong>Weather: </strong>Light Rain</td> \n" +
            "    </tr> \n" +
            "    <tr> \n" +
            "     <td><strong>Tempratue: </strong>70 C</td> \n" +
            "    </tr> \n" +
            "    <tr> \n" +
            "     <td><strong>Visibility: </strong>Limited</td> \n" +
            "    </tr> \n" +
            "    <tr> \n" +
            "     <td><strong>Runs open: </strong>0</td> \n" +
            "    </tr>\n" +
            "   </tbody>\n" +
            "  </table>\n" +
            " </body>\n" +
            "</html>"
            + "<head></head>";

    Document html = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring);
    Elements tds = html.getElementsByTag("td");
    for (Element td : tds) {
        //String tdStrongText = td.childNode(0).childNodes().get(0).toString();
        String tdStrongText = td.select("strong").text();
        System.out.print(tdStrongText + " : ");
        String tdText = td.childNode(1).toString();
        System.out.println(tdText);
    }
}
```

Check out code on [github](https://github.com/asharn/stackoverflow-interactive-answers/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/question/answer/LetsPlayWithJSoup.java).