# How to use .contains on childList mutation?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am using MutationObserver and want to check a class selector on `target.className` but I get an error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')
```

so I looked at classList's prototype and it has `.contains` method and I did the following `target.classList.prototype.contains("OverlayWrapper")` and I still get the same error.

I don't understand why I am getting this error as I am trying to check for a partial `className` .

Edit: I have added a snapshot of the console[image]

Edit: I have made an example for the code, it is the bare minimum where I am looking for a class that contains `popUp__wrapper` being added to the DOM. (an error will be in the console when we press the open button) [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahassan/9yznLm4u/2/)

Comment: You need to show an actual [MCVE](/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Right now it looks like your `target` is not an element, but just a plain text `Node`.

Comment: As others have indicated, please post actual code the reproduces the issue so we may best assist you here. not just a picture of some code

Comment: @wOxxOm I have posted an example of code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues**

- `mutation.addedNodes` is an [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (collection of nodes). So obviously `classList` not exists in it.
- Your class `popUp__wrapper` is suffixed with a an `scxdxcfd`. No class with exact name `popUp__wrapper`.

**Solution**

```
let wrapperEl = Array.from(mutation.addedNodes) // convert NodeList to array
      .filter(n => n.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE) // remove text nodes
      .find(n => n.matches('[class*=popUp__wrapper]')) // search for class
```

If you need to check `popUp__wrapper` available inside the node, use `querySelector` instead of `matches`

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/qjeafxd8/20/

**References**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text

Comment: This is great. I have some questions. why use a filter? and how do we know if the array has any method on it from just console?

Comment: The filter is used to omit the [text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195868/what-is-a-text-node-its-uses-document-createtextnode), we want only the element nodes. And yes, the console is the best option to learn new methods or you can also use [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)